# How to return data if a value falls within a range

Tags: worksheet-function

I am trying to make a formula to calculate certain costs associated with a property value, based on its value:

```
Value of Property     Rate to apply   Deduction
Up to €92,407           0%            Nil
€92,407 – €126,403      2%            €1,848.14
€126,403 – €172,348     5%            €5,640.23
€172,348 – €287,213     7%            €9,087.19
€287,213 – €574,323     8%            €11,959.32
over €574,323           6%            Nil
```

So when I enter the actual value of a property, say €275,000 somewhere in it my spreadsheet should look up in which range it falls, pick up the correct % and make the calculation.

Can you please advise the best way for this?

Answer (score 3):

Enter the property values with only **one** value per cell, **sorted ascending**. Enter only the threshold value, not both from-to values in one cell.

Then you can use Vlookup with "TRUE" as the last parameter, which will find the next value that is less than or equal to the lookup value.

In the screenshot below, the property value is entered in F1. To return the Rate, use

```
=VLOOKUP(F1,$A$2:$C$7,2,TRUE)
```

To return the deduction, use

```
=VLOOKUP(F1,$A$2:$C$7,3,TRUE)
```

[image]